# datepicker is not active after the submit event of the partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working on an asp.net mvc4 application where in i have a regular view that uses a shared view and the regular view has 3 tabs namely tabs-1 tabs-2 and tabs-3.

Each of the tabid has an ajax begin form to call a partial view associated with that tab.

Each partial view has controls rendering output  on button submit to same partial view on reselecting the controls of the partial view the datepicker is not active until the regular view page is refreshed.

please tel me  as of what could be the reason that the date picker doesnt appear before pagerefresh.kindly help me out with solution

The code snippet of the regular view is as follows

```
  @model EMPApp.Models.leavedetails
   @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Leave Report";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutHRAdmin.cshtml";
 }

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var message = '@TempData["Report"]';
   if (message) {
      alert(message);
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".AttReportgrid tr").each(function () {

        $('input:text[value=]').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });

        $('tr td:nth-child(2)').find('select').attr("disabled", true);
        $('tr td:nth-child(4)').find('select').attr("disabled", true);

    })
    $('#ddlDepartment').change(function () {
        $.getJSON('/HRAdmin/getEmpid/' + $('#ddlDepartment').val(), function (cnlistjson) {
            $('#ddlEmpid').attr("disabled", false);
            $("#ddlEmpid option").remove();
            var empIdhtml = "<option>" + '--select--' + "</option>";
            $("#ddlEmpid").append(empIdhtml);
            for (i = 0; i < $(cnlistjson).length; i++) {

                empIdhtml = "<option>" + $(cnlistjson)[i].Empid + "</option>";
                $("#ddlEmpid").append(empIdhtml);
            }

        })

    })

    $('#ddlDepartment1').change(function () {

        $.getJSON('/HRAdmin/getEmpLeavetype1/' + $('#ddlDepartment1').val(), function (cnlistjson) {
            //alert(cnlistjson);
            $('#ddlleave1').attr("disabled", false);

            $("#ddlleave1 option").remove();
            var empleavehtml1 = "<option>" + '--select--' + "</option>";
            $("#ddlleave1").append(empleavehtml1);
            debugger;

            for (i = 0; i < $(cnlistjson).length; i++) {

                empleavehtml1 = "<option value='" + $(cnlistjson)[i].leavedid + "'>" +     $(cnlistjson)[i].leavetype + "</option>";
                $("#ddlleave1").append(empleavehtml1);
            }

            $('#LeaveReportfromdatepicker1').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#LeaveReporttodatepicker1').attr("disabled", false);

        })

    })


})
```

Comment: reinitialize datpicker after refreshing partial view

Comment: reinitialization in partial view o regular view?PLEASE HELP ME OUT WID ASAMPLE CODE SNIPPET

Comment: after aappending html reinitialize by doing ``$("#txtboxid").datpicker();``